# Does MediaElement.js include logic for adaptive streaming support?

Tags: mediaelement.js

With MediaElement.js, can you specify a M3U8 source (read Apple HLS source) as well as a F4M Flash adaptive manifest and have it play the M3U8 source where support is available (iOS, Safari Mac desktop, Android 2.3.x and higher on most devices), and use a F4M manifest for Flash playback elsewhere? On videoRx.com, I've written my own JS lib to make appropriate decisions along this path, but I like the MediaElement.js structure.

Quick example, I use Wowza Media Server to serve mobile/desktop adaptive streams and it can automatically create M3U8 and F4M manifests.